# How many times can these loops execute?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Hey I'm trying to figure out the growth rate of the nested loop, I know the first loop is will go around 100 times since it can only run 100 times but the 2nd loop I'm not too sure about.
Anyone can help me out?

```cpp
29  for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i)
30  {
31     for (int j = 0; m[i] < m[j] && m[j] != 0; ++j)
32     {
33        product = product + (m[i] * n[j]);
34     }
35  }
```

The full code is here

```cpp
01  const int MAX = 100;
02  int lowerCount;
03  int higherCount;
04  int equalCount;
05  int product;
06
07  lowerCount = higherCount = equalCount = 0;
08  product = 0;
09
10  for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
11  {
12     if (m[i]  < n[i])
13     {
14         ++higherCount;
15     }
16     else
17     {
18        if (m[i] == n[i])
19        {
20           ++lowerCount;
21        }
22        else
23        {
24           ++equalCount;
25        }
26     }
27  }
28
29  for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
30  {
31     for (int j = 0; m[i] < m[j] && m[j] != 0; j++)
32     {
33        product = product + (m[i] * n[j]);
34     }
35  }
36
37  cout << "lowerCount " << lowerCount << "\n";
38  cout << "equalCount " << equalCount << "\n";`
39  cout << "higherCount " << higherCount << "\n";
40  cout << "product " << product << "\n"";
```

Comment: My magic ball doesn't show the values of m[i] and m[j] :(

Comment: I just need to work out the growth rate, I don't have the values for m[i] and m[j] sorry :(

Comment: Hope you find the right answer for this, jokes apart ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer you are looking for is O(N^2 + 2N / (1/2N) + 3n^3)  this is clear if you use Ballmers algorithm to work out complexity.

Comment: Can you explain how you ended with this? And isn't 2N / (1/2N) == 4N

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, when calculating algorithm complexity you can give big-O for best, worst and average case.

In the case of two nested loops the best case is O(n) - if the inner loop is executed only once(I am ignoring the fact that both loops may process only one iteration).
The worst one is O(n*k) - first loop iterates n-times, the inner one iterates k-times.

As Asier has sad we do not know what is in m[i] so there is not idea what the average complexity will be.